# How do i remove this value in a list while using objects

Tags: python, class, object

I have a code where I need to remove an entry of a person from a school roster. At the very bottom of the code, I have the parameter of Stern, the final print statement prints the roster without Stern. I don't know how to remove the person from the list since there is a first name and a last name, and I am not allowed to put both first names and last name as a parameter. I don't really know if I can use the .pop() or .remove() in this case. Can I just remove the name by removing the index from the list? Ive also tried delattr

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, first, last, gpa):
        self.first = first # first name
        self.last = last   # last name
        self.gpa = gpa     # grade point average

    def get_gpa(self):
        return self.gpa

    def get_last(self):
        return self.last

    def to_string(self):
        return self.first + ' ' + self.last + ' (GPA: ' + str(self.gpa) + ')'

class Course:
    def __init__(self):
        self.roster = []  # list of Student objects

    **def drop_student(self, student):
         #space where i remove one student**

    def add_student(self, student):
        self.roster.append(student)

    def count_students(self):
        return len(self.roster)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    course = Course()

    course.add_student(Student('Henry', 'Nguyen', 3.5))
    course.add_student(Student('Brenda', 'Stern', 2.0))
    course.add_student(Student('Lynda', 'Robinson', 3.2))
    course.add_student(Student('Sonya', 'King', 3.9))

    print('Course size:', course.count_students(),'students')
    
    course.drop_student('Stern')
    print('Course size after drop:', course.count_students(),'students')
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be using `remove`. But you will have to grab the student first (e.g. by filtering/searching the list).

```py
    def drop_student(self, first, last):
        matches = list(filter(lambda student: student.first == first and student.last == last, self.roster))
        if len(matches) > 1:
            raise Exception("Student not unique")
        elif len(matches) < 1:
            print(f"No student named {first} {last}")
        else:
            self.roster.remove(matches[0])
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, but I don't know what lambda does

Comment: lambda is an inline function definition: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions

Answer (score 0):

In the end of your code

```
course.dropstudent('Stren')
```

Can't be called because in your property definition you pass "Student" object as a parameter so when you call your property you can't call it with a 'String'.

Use instead

```
Stud_Stren = Student('Brenda', 'Stern', 2.0)
course.dropstudent(Stud_Stren)
```

And take the code that [Lukas Schmid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11437648/lukas-schmid) had given to you for your "drop_student" property and give it some modification to use the attribute of your student object (First name, last name, gpa), Or take it as it is if you don't want to pass a student object and replace your call by

```
course.dropstudent('Brenda', 'Stern')
```

Answer (score 0):

You write `course.drop_student('Stern')`,
but the name is not sufficient to identify a student.
So first you must clarify the key to retrieve a student, for example (lastname, firstname).
Then you can write something like :

```
def drop_student(self, last, first):
    for i,student in enumerate(self.roster):
        if student.last==last and student.first==first:
            self.roster.pop(i)
...
course.drop_student('Stern','Brenda')
```